# Assign value to variable from closure - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures

Im trying to assign Image (which downloads from API) from closure to a variable. Closure which implements execution is an escaping closure.

Since thats escaping closure, I receive "Missing return in a function expected to return 'UIImage?'"

Kindly advice how to fix this

```
 var posterPath: UIImage? {
    get {
        let url = posterData.medium[0].url
        self.imageFor(for: url) { (image) in
            return image
        }
    }
  //returns error here as there is no return statement
}
```

Comment: How is this supposed to work, you are making an asynchronous call inside a computed property? As I see it `get` will always return nil until that image has been downloaded

Comment: Yes..correct. How can I fix this,.any ideas?

Comment: Dowload the image separately and then set the property (posterPath) in the callback method, There are a ton of examples and questions on how to download images so with some googling you should be able to find something that fits your use-case

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by having an escaping param in your function, something like this:

```
func getTheImageFromApi(success: @escaping (_ image: UIImage) -> ()){

    let url = posterData.medium[0].url
        self.imageFor(for: url) { (image) in
            success(image)
     }

}
```

Then using this function in your view controller:

```
var posterPath: UIImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getTheImageFromApi(success: { image in
        self.posterPath = image
    })
}
```